# Crossing Brooklyn Ferry

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the poem *Crossing Brooklyn Ferry* by Walt Whitman, it seems to me the narrator is crossing a passage with a ferry. But doesn't the title literally mean he is crossing the ferry itself?

Comment: It is common, in parts of the US, for a route across a body of water to be referred to as a "ferry".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Walt Whitman wrote in the 19th century, when *"crossing the ferry"* was a more common phrase than either *"crossing by the ferry"* or *"crossing on the ferry"*.

[See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crossing+the+ferry%2Ccrossing+by+ferry%2Ccrossing+by+the+ferry%2Ccrossing+on+the+ferry&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrossing%20the%20ferry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrossing%20by%20ferry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrossing%20by%20the%20ferry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrossing%20on%20the%20ferry%3B%2Cc0).

Why does this make sense? In the 19th century, *ferry* meant not only the boat, but also the place on the river where you crossed using the boat.

From [Webster's International Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=qL8WAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=webster+international+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIyNKXybvixgIVyTY-Ch27SQXl#v=onepage&q=ferry&f=false), 1892:

> A place, also a boat, for transporting passengers or freight over a river, etc.

Comment: That's really interesting. Can you back it up with other examples from a corpus or an explanation of why it made sense? I'd be really interested. I can't see why anyone would make "ferry" mean "stretch of water". Thanks

Comment: @chasly from UK: done. Indeed *ferry* ***did*** mean "place along a river where a *ferryboat* operated", as you might be able to deduce by names of towns like "Harper's Ferry".

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ferry

Comment: @chaslyfromUK to me it seems a perfectly logical transfer of meaning. "Ferry" the vehicle becomes "ferry" the place, as in "it's next to Fulton ferry."  The name refers to the ferry crossing itself (analogous to a bridge), not actually to the stretch of water.  Note that Fulton Street in Brooklyn is arguably an extension of its namesake in Manhattan, as they were once joined by Fulton ferry.

Comment: @phoog: actually, according the the OED, *ferry* has meant both the place of crossing and the boat used to cross since the late 13th century (their citation for the place is 4 years earlier than for the boat, but they have one for *ferryman* 100 years before that, so the record really can't tell which came first). The word originally came from some Scandinavian language in which it meant the boat.

Comment: +1 Also, Locals regularly refer to a particular ferry terminal by saying *I'm at the ferry* whether or not a boat is present. Similarly one might say *I'm at the train* meaning at the train station.

Answer (score 2):

OED sense 2 (“Now somewhat *rare”):*

> A crossing over a river or other stretch of water which is served by a ferry boat. Also: a place at which a ferry boat departs or lands.

In sum, especially in older usage, *ferry* could refer to the stretch of water traversed by the boat (and its passengers) as well as to the boat itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ferries in the old days were often not so much a boat as a raft pulled across the water by a rope attached at each end to opposite shores. In these cases, the ferry includes the rope and by extension the route travelled by the raft as it's towed along the rope. Therefore "crossing a ferry" had a meaning very similar to "crossing a bridge", i.e. "following a guided route across the water".